# Is there any way to show top seller product by date range in frontend in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3.5-p1, php-7.2, best-seller

Is there anyway to display best seller products by date range? For example recent last 7 days or recent 30 days or recent 60 days, etc.
I have got a help that thing. But it is in Magento 1.9, not 2.x from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48299911/get-last-7-days-best-selling-items-magento-1-9 and I've tried a lot in Magento 2.3, but shows a blank page that's main code are given below:

```
    $bestSellers = $this->_bestSellersCollectionFactory->create();
                         //->setModel('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');

    $bestSellers->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array(
                'from'=> date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-7 days')),
                'to' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                                ));

   foreach ($bestSellers as $product) {
            $productIds[] = $product->getProductId();
        }

   $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create()->addIdFilter($productIds);
   $collection->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addFinalPrice()
            ->addTaxPercents()
            ->addAttributeToSelect($this->_catalogConfig->getProductAttributes())
            ->addStoreFilter($this->getStoreId())
            ->addUrlRewrite()
            ->setVisibility($this->catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInSiteIds());
            //->setPageSize($this->getProductsCount());

    return $collection;
```

I cann't understand where I'm wrong and how to implement this thing. If any one knows, please help me. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I did the collection like this:

```
// some more lines in advance - let me know if I should append them
    public function getBestSellerCollection($from, $to) 
{
    $bestSellerProdcutCollection = $this->_collectionFactory->create();
    $bestSellerProdcutCollection->setModel('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->setPeriod('day');    
    $datefrom = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-'.$from.' day'));
    $dateto = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-'.$to.' day'));
    $bestSellerProdcutCollection->addFieldToFilter('period',array('gt'=>$datefrom));
    $bestSellerProdcutCollection->getSelect()->group('Product_Name')->order('Product_Name ASC'); //DESC ASC
    return $bestSellerProdcutCollection;
}
```

Then later you can call

```
$collection =  $block->getBestSellerCollection(30,0); // last 30 days
```